# a question about the bipartition of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Please,could you help at the following question?

Show that if G is a simple graph that has n vertexes,where n>4,then G is bipartite or the complement of G is bipartite.

I tried induction,but it didn't work.

Comment: peak=vertex? Sorry, I've just never heard that terminology before

Comment: I've done the editing.Please,could you answer me?

Comment: Without additional hypotheses, this statement seems to be false.

Comment: Why is it false?

Comment: Gregory Puleo,can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: experiment with some small non-bipartite graphs and you should find a counterexample.

Comment: The number of vetices is bigger than 4.

Comment: The OP [has since asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762863/a-question-about-simple-graphs-2?rq=1) about showing that either a graph or its complement is _connected_.  I suspect that that is what this question should have said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement given is false, consider the counterexample: cycle $C_5$ of length five, its complement is also $C_5$, thus both are non-bipartite.